# Chrome says "Cannot GET / " in Angular 4 - Observable

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I have tried to add observable data into the service. Until that application worked perfectly.

[image]

My Service is as follows

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/Observable/of';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

@Injectable()
export class HeroServiceService {

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    this.messageService.add("Hero Service:fetched heroes");
    return of(HEROES);
  }

  constructor(public messageService: MessageService) { }

}
```

The way I called the service:

```
getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }
```

Comment: Try this as your `of` import: `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';`

Comment: No it doesn't work. Do i need to go for npm install again?

Comment: That wouldn't hurt, give it a try.

Comment: Actually I'm trying this https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: No it didn't. I tried twice.

Comment: It worked. I have just change the position of where i have import two libraries(Observable, of)

Answer (score 1):

I changed the position of libraries where i have import them. I think that we have to import them just after @angular/core.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class HeroServiceService {

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    this.messageService.add("Hero Service:fetched heroes");
    return of(HEROES);
  }

  constructor(public messageService: MessageService) { }

}
```